# Definition of the derivative: difference between two limiting processes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Say I have $f(x) = 2x^2 + x - 1$.

Is there a difference between using the following two limit processes?

1. $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$
2. $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$

I've applied both processes to get the derivative in terms of $c$ for #1 and in terms of $x$ for #2.

It seems like both work fine. Are there any pros or cons for either? I've tried to look up information online on this but had no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: They're both equivalent ways of expressing the concept of a derivative. One just might be easier to use than the other in different cases or scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Those two definitions for the derviative of a function $f$ are equivalent, which I am going to prove right now:

$$\frac{d f}{d x}(c) = \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$$

By substitution of variable $x = x' + c \implies x' = x - c$ we have that:

$$\frac{d f}{d x}(c) = \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} = \lim_{x'\to 0}\frac{f(c + x') - f(c)}{x'} $$

By further changing the variable $x'$ as $x' \rightarrow \Delta x $ we get

$$\frac{d f}{d x}(c) = \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(c + \Delta x) - f(c)}{\Delta x} $$

Because of their equivalency, whenever you try to find the derivative of one function with the one limit process or the other, the result is going to be the same.

As far as which is better, there is no answer to that. Every time you use the representation that seems to lead you to the solution more easily and its straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, they are equivalent. The second method is most commonly used because with it the point in which the function is differentiated is not used in the limit opperation.
Let $f$ be a real function differentiable at a point $x$. We can write:

$$f^\prime(x) = lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(\mathbf{x})}{\Delta x}$$

Whereas using the first limit, we would have to write $x$ as the limit point:
$$f^\prime(x) = lim_{u \to x} \frac{f(u) - f(x)}{u - x}$$

In the same way, this method is usually more helpful when working with multiple variables and partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}= lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x . e_i) - f(\mathbf{x})}{\Delta x}$$